# make command to replace constants in code

Tags: c, unix, makefile

Sorry if this is a primitive question but I am really new in linux. Is there a way to replace constants in source code while building the application using `make` command?

I know the next possible method is to change the header files used in the source code, but I ask this because I have to program multiple microcontrollers and each one should have a unique integer as its number (this number is assigned as a constant in the code).

Any tips will be appreciated!

Comment: you should take a look at sed and grep, they provide the functionality you need

Comment: Or if your source is being handled by the C preprocessor anyway, pass in a suitable `#define` with `make -Dconstant=value`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is often done by defining preprocessor macros when invoking the compiler, e.g.:

```
# Makefile
NUMBER := 42
%.o : %.c
    gcc -c -o $@ ${CPPFLAGS} ${CFLAGS} -DNUMBER=${NUMBER} $<
```

In a source file:

```
// some.c
int number = NUMBER;
```

Comment: It is almost always better to avoid redefining implicit rules.  A single line Makefile will suffice: `CPPFLAGS=-DNUMBER=N` (And perhaps a second line like: `all: foo` so the user can simply type `make` instead of `make foo`.)

Comment: @WilliamPursell: I agree that `-D...` should be put into `CPPFLAGS`. I prefer disabling all built-in rules for my own makefiles because they are not good enough for me. For example, I like to trigger recompilation when makefiles change, hence my object files also depend on their makefile.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a *C language macro* passed on the command line to the compiler. The usual `Makefile` snippet would look something like

```
CFLAGS = -DVERSION_INT=42 -DVERSION_STRING=\"Frobozz Magic Frobnicator (TM)\"

main: main.c
         $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ main.c
```

In main.c you might have

```
static int version = VERSION_INT;
static char vers[] = VERSION_STRING;
```

Comment: `-D` options are intended for the pre-processor, and belong in `CPPFLAGS` rather than `CFLAGS`.

Comment: @WilliamPursell I disagree. `CPPFLAGS` is a random invention of J. Random Hacker, more or less. `CFLAGS` is the POSIX way as per http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/make.html  and I value portability very much. But anyone's MMV. :-)

Comment: Interesting.  It is surprisingly difficult to separate long-standing convention with actual standards.  Thanks for pointing that out!